# Flexicious Ultimate DataGrid keep focus in itemEditor when clicking on scroll bar

Tags: focus, scrollbar, itemeditor, flexicious

Is there a way I could do this?

I want the user to be able to click in an editable cell, and then if they happen to click on the scroll bar for the DataGrid I want to keep the itemEditor showing and not go back to the normal dataField.

How could I make this happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

which version of the product are you on? on the latest version, it does not seem to be behaving the way you describe it. If you have a valid subscription, feel free to contact support and they will get you the latest version.